# Android: ListView link several list

Tags: android, listview

I want to link many List at the ListView.
**First List:** USA, EU, Asia, Afrika ...
Then when i click USA it should come the **Second List:** Virginia, North Carolina, Ohio ...
Than click Virginia the **third List:** Virginia Beach, Norfolk, Chesapeake ...
And at the end by clicking in the **third List** should come my Created **html Page** at the WebView. Thanks!

Comment: Most probably you need multiple activities for hierarchy like this. But better you start off with a interaction story board to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, when I click **USA** should the next List (usa[]) appear, and than **Virginia** should the next List (virginia[]) appear.

public class customlistview extends ListActivity 
{
    private ListView lv1;

```
private String continent[] = {
        "USA", "EU", "Asia", "Afrika", "Australia"
};
private String usa[] = {
        "Alabama", "Virginia", "Arizona", "Arkansas",
        "California", "Florida", "Kansas", "Indiana",
        "Michigan", "Ohio", "New York", "North Carolina"
};
private String virginia[] = {
        "Virginia Beach", "Norfolk", "Chesapeake",
        "Richmond", "Hampton", "Arlington"
};

@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , continent));


    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {

        // TODO

    }
}
```

}